# How to get the xml files of an apk file back to how it was?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, apk, decompiler

About 1.5 years ago I uploaded my app (made in Android Studio) to the Google Play Store. During the period between then and now, I've been trying to make some other apps and during the development of one of those apps I did something to my Android Studio which made it crash or something. I've lost my code but got the APK file, so I decompiled it using [decompiler.com](https://decompiler.com). This gives me the Java code back nicely, but there are an incredible amount of XML files seperated over different folders. Is there any possibility to merge these together to get the original XML code back again?

Thanks in advance,

Koen

Comment: Jadx and apktool can decompile APKs and convert XML files from their binary for to plain XML.

Comment: I don't want to convert the XML files, I want to get them back to how it was in my project. I now see a lot of XML files with just a few lines of XML code.

Comment: The XML files you get are those you have in your project. Because of used libraries it may be more than those you have created yourself. As in a compiled APK it is unknown if an XML files was added by a library or by you you get them all. The same is true for the source code, you get the complete source code, including all libraries.

Comment: So I would have to add together all the XML lines myself? That seems impossible to me.

Comment: Nobody said that reconstructing a project for a decompiled app would be easy. Next time always make sure to have a recent backup saved in a place where it survives common disasters (e.g. saved to a Git repo, copied to a Dropbox folder).

Answer (score 0):

try this app, for decompile apk

https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx.mirror/

Comment: I've already decompiled it, but I get a resources and sources folder. In the sources folder I can go into another folder and get all the Java code without any problem. In the resources folder, I go into the 'res' folder and see a lot of folders. Each folder then has a few files with XML code. I don't know how to put all this code back together. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Usually if your apk is not signed apk, then issues get resolved. If it is signed one, then you need to identify the xml and then extract it.